# How does Prolog handle this query

Tags: list, prolog, logic, head, tail

Considering the following definition:

```
my_append([], L, L).
my_append([H|T], L, [H|NewTail]):-
my_append(T, L, NewTail).
```

And a possible usage, and its output:

```
?- my_append([1,2,5], [3,4], L).
L = [1, 2, 5, 3, 4].
```

Could someone help me understanding how does it work?

Comment: This is one of the first Prolog programs anyone learns. Isn't it explained in the textbook?

Answer (score 0):

This work like a recusive function.
There is two step (1&2) to define a recursive function
my_append(A,B,C)  take two list A & B and build a list that is the appending of elements of A and B (call this result C).
Here the third parameter act as an result of the function (that not true but a good first approximation).

1) The base case.
**my_append([], L, L).**

In the case where the first Liste is empty, trivaly the result is everything that can be put in second parameter.

2) The recursive case.
**my_append([H|T], L, [H|NewTail]):-
    my_append(T, L, NewTail).**

In the case where the first list isn't empty the first list have the form [Head|Tail], and we want that head to be the head of our result (the third arg).
The second line give details on how build the end/tail of the result.
The end/tail of the result is a appending of the shorten first arg and the second arg: This is the recursion; the problem is express using it own definition but on a list witch is one element shorter.

So day after day the first arg is shorter and shorter until the base case match.

Note that if you call my_append() with parameters that aren't bound variable(know variables if you prefers) then the result can be undeterministic : aka each call will return a different solution until there is no more solution.

I call the method like this :

```
my_append([1,2],[3,4],L)
```

and it match

```
my_append([1,2],[3,4],[1,2,3,4])


it's logicals implication are given by :
my_append([1,2],[3,4],L)   => match 2)
so the reduction is :
   my_append([1,2],[3,4],[1,I])
where my_append([2],[3,4],I) must be reduce.

my_append([2],[3,4],I)   => match 2)
so the reduction is :
   my_append([2],[3,4],[1,2,J])
where my_append([],[3,4],J) must be reduce.

my_append([],[3,4],K)   => match 1)
so the reduction is :
   my_append([],[3,4],[3,4]) where all variables are know/bind.
```

so we "de-stack"

```
K = [3,4]     (base case)
J = [3,4]     (recursion case)
I = [2,3,4]   (recursion case)
L = [1,2,3,4] (call)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive function.

It splits the first list into head pieces and when it is empty it takes the second list and successively adds the head to the front.

You can imagine this as multiple calls to my_append as follows:

```
my_append([1,2,5], [3,4], L)
```

which calls:

```
my_append([2,5], [3,4], L)
```

which calls:

```
my_append([5], [3,4], L)
```

which then calls the base case:

```
my_append([], [3,4], L)
```

This is then returned in the reverse order as follows:

L is [3,4], then L is [5,3,4], then L is [2,5,3,4], then L is [1,2,5,3,4] and the function ends.